# What are some of the pros of being a remote recruiter versus a contract recruiter?

Tags: recruitment, telecommute

I applied for a driver recruiting job. The company called me and I told them I am looking for a remote recruiting position, NOT contract. Meaning I would be their employee, but work from home.

The gentleman I spoke with said he thought that may work due to my experience.

He called me today and his VP is willing to consider the idea, though the company has never done that.

So next week they are having a meeting about it. I'd like to present the company with some of its benefits, not just for myself, but for them as well.

What are some pros of being a remote recruiter?

Comment: none, if you have to ask because you must have little to no experience as a remote employee, and I think you may have misconstrued the meaning of contract. Unless you're intending to be some sort of 'casual' worker, a contract is normal whether remote or not. Good luck all the same.

Comment: Are you trying to compare working remotely vs. working in the office? Or remotely working as an employee vs. as a contractor? If the former, then not being a contractor seems kind of irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

> What are some pros of remote recruitment?

Some pros I can think of are:

- Most importantly, **no time/money wasted commuting to work**. It is not rare for people to take a whole hour or more to get to work and the same to get back. You can start working as soon as you wake up if you want to. Plus, sometimes offices are not as comfortable as your home may be.
- From the company's point of view, they don't have to provide you with a **desk** or some other space in their office for you to use, sparing them from having to purchase and install more desks and chairs.
- Also from the company's view, you are **sparing** them from **other expenses** people working on the office might use, like electricity, internet and phone usage, and other gear (like computer and accessories). However, for you this means you may have to use your own resources instead, so be sure to analyze if this is something you are ok with.
- Your professional experience and know-how is not affected by *where* you are located, so your remote work would be as good as it could be on office. Now days virtual meetings can be as good as on-premise meetings, so you can keep them up to date without problems. Also, Instant Messaging enables for quick follow-ups and questions they/you may have.

I hope you find this pros useful for your arguments.

Comment: Also, assuming you're remote enough, it means you could easily attend/create recruitment events in your area without needing to incur extra traveling expenses to reach that area. One negative could be taxes, especially if you're the only full-time employee in your state. This could just make matters more complicated for the company. I wouldn't mention that part, but I would research that question in case they bring it up as an objection.

Comment: good observation @StephanBranczyk

Answer (score -1):

Contract Recruiter Pros:

- **Less commitment.** Many people think of an employer relationship in an unhealthy way: that of the employee owing something to the employer. But if an employee provides value in the work they do it should even that out. Working as a contractor allows both the employee and the employer to test out the fit before making a commitment to providing all benefits of an FTE
- **Paid Weekly (usually).** Typically 3rd party firms who take you on their payroll will pay you weekly. They do this to bill the client weekly as well. It's a nice benefit for the contractor.
- **Higher hourly rate.** Depending on your situation, you could end up making more money as a contractor. For this reason, technical employees like developers love contract work. You won't have to allocate part of your check toward company benefits that are often mandated.

Remote Recruiter Pros:

- **You can work anywhere.** Home, coffee shop, shared workspace, train, plane, wherever.
- **Distractions.** Remote employment is a blessing for some and a curse for others. It allows you to control your day without the distractions of coworkers asking you for help or unexpected meetings popping up. That said, the distractions of TV/laundry/your smartphone/pet/etc. can be a huge obstacle for some to get over.
- **Unique benefits.** Some companies treat their remote employees a little differently than in-office FTE's. This is because those remote employees don't get the benefits that are IN the office (usually snacks, games, coffee, standing desks, etc.). They may help you fund an office at home, or pay for a shared workspace. Just ask!